# How to get permission to edit the ontology?

Tags: dbpedia

I'm trying to map some infoboxes from Wikipedia to the DBpedia ontology.

According to http://mappings.dbpedia.org/index.php/How_to_edit_the_DBpedia_Ontology

But I don't have permission to edit the ontology, nor the wiki pages, although I created an account.

How to get permissions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need editor rights, next to your user account.

The procedure to get to start mapping is on the [Main page](http://mappings.dbpedia.org/index.php/Main_Page) of the Mappings wiki:

> **Prerequisites**
>
> If you would like to edit the mappings or ontology schema this is what you need:
>
> - a user account on this wiki (login/sign up)
> - editor rights
>
>   - they will be given to you within a couple of days
>   - if not, please ask for editor rights at dbpedia-discussion@lists.sourceforge.net. Include your user name in the message.
>   - once you got editor rights, please provide some information about yourself on your user wiki page
> - a namespace for the language you want to write mappings for
>
>   - if the namespace does not exist already (see the left side bar) please request it at dbpedia-discussion@lists.sourceforge.net

(Edit: added core point to answer.)